# Chrome Extension: Trying to substitute three DOM values as variables in an URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Let me first explain why I want to do this. For my work I mainly use two sites. On the first one I receive a customers postal code, house number and potentially a house number addition. On the second site I have to fill in this information to get to the right page in our system. So it saves me a lot of time if this second site could be automatically loaded or can be triggered with a click on a button.

The DOM elements are in an HTML input tag in the value attribute. They look like something this:

```
<input type="text id="postalCode" value="1234AB">
<input type="text id="houseNumber" value="1">
<input type="text id="houseNumberAddition" value="A">
```

This is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Speedy",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "-",
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus"
 ],
"background": { 
  "scripts": ["script.js"]
},

"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
           "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```

And this is my script.js:

```
var postalCode = document.getElementById("postalCode").value;
var houseNumber = document.getElementById("houseNumber").value;
var houseNumberAddition = document.getElementById("houseNumberAddition").value;


function openSecondSite(info,tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({  
      url: "https://example.com/search?postalcode=" + postalCode + "&housenumber=" + houseNumber + "?addition=" + houseNumberAddition,
    });           
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
   title: "Open this customer in a new tab", 
   contexts:["selection"], 
   onclick: openSecondSite,
});
```

With code similar to this I was able to select to postal code and search just for that. I've read that I have to use a content script to do anything with DOM content but can't figure out what changes to make in my files.

I hope someone can help me out with this!

Disclaimer: this is my first time on StackOverflow and one of the first times fiddling with JavaScript, so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick handler in the background page should run a content script to extract the data first.

background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'go',
  title: 'Open this customer in a new tab', 
  contexts: ['selection'], 
}, () => chrome.runtime.lastError);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'content-grab-data.js',
    frameId: 0,
  }, ([data]) => {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: 'https://example.com/search' +
           '?postalcode=' + data.postalCode +
           '&housenumber=' + data.houseNumber +
           '&addition=' + data.houseNumberAddition,
    });
  });
});
```

content-grab-data.js - the last expression will be picked up by executeScript.

```
var postalCode = document.getElementById("postalCode").value;
var houseNumber = document.getElementById("houseNumber").value;
var houseNumberAddition = document.getElementById("houseNumberAddition").value;

var result = {postalCode, houseNumber, houseNumberAddition};
result;
```

Note, it's better to use nonpersistent background pages aka [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).